# Access to Shopware API from CLI command without Client Credentials

Tags: rest, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I would like to call some Shopware API endpoint from CLI command (user is not logged in).

I am able to create Client Credentials and use it for my calls - but it requires to generate Client Credentials manually by user in "Settings > System > Integrations".

[image: creating client credentials]

Is it possible to avoid generating Client Credentials and then copy/paste to some config?

My only idea is to generate Client Credentials directly in plugin code and store them in DB as a plugin config for example:

```php
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;

class Config
{
    public function __construct(
        private SystemConfigService $systemConfigService,
    )

    public function setCredentials(string $clientId, string $clientSecret)
    {
        $this->systemConfigService->set('CompanyPluginName.config.clientId', $clientId);
        $this->systemConfigService->set('CompanyPluginName.config.clientSecret', $clientSecret);
    }
}
```

Do you have any better ideas how I can authenticate to API - without creating and passing any credentials manually by plugin user?  ️ I will be so grateful for ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: currently I am not sure if that works or if you need to configure credentials in shopware-cli then

---

I would not suggest to store a token clear text in the databae.

You could use the shopware-cli tool

https://sw-cli.fos.gg/commands/project/

It has a ready made CLI command to call the API:

```
shopware-cli project admin-api POST "/search/tax" -- \
-d '{"limit": 1}' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

You can use the same command with `--show-token` to only obtain a token.